# Small "embeddable" database that can also be synced over the network?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, couchdb

I am looking for a small database that can be "embedded" into my Python application without running a separate server, as one can do with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [Metakit](http://www.equi4.com/metakit/). I don't need an SQL database, in fact storing free-form data like Python dictionaries or JSON is preferable.

The other requirement is that to be able to run an instance of the database on a server, and have instances of my application (clients) sync the database with the server (two-way), similar to what [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)  replication can do.

Is there a database that will do this?

Comment: do you need to support 2 way sync?

Comment: @tosh: yes (added it to the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need an SQL database, what's wrong with CouchDB? You can spawn a local process to serve the DB, and you could easily write a server wrapper to allow only access from your app. I'm not sure about the access story, but I believe the latest Ubuntu uses CouchDB for synchronizeable user-level data.

Comment: The only problem with CouchDB is dependencies and size. My application is windows/linux/osx, the installers for CouchDB are twice the size of the app itself.

Comment: The entire Erlang VM, which is required is a potentially large install, I agree. CouchDB itself is actually pretty svelte. However, I don't think you're going to find anything that fits all your requirements without a large dependency; synchronization is hard.

Comment: It seems that if I want the to use fancy sync features of couchdb, and not roll my own, I really need to require couchdb!

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, it sounds like you could get by using `pickle` and FTP.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the perfect job for CouchDB: 2 way sync is incredibly easy, schema-less JSON documents are the native format. If you're using python, [couchdb-python](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/) is a great way to work with CouchDB.

Comment: Yes except for the dependency on erlang, which makes including couchdb prohibitively large. Erlang seems to have compilers to native code, is it possible to make a smaller CouchDB package that way?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need clients to work offline and then resync when they reconnect to the network? I don't know if [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org) can handle the offline client scenario, but if the client is online all the time, MongoDB might be a good solution too. It has pretty goode python [support](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Python+Language+Center). Still a separate process, but perhaps easier to get running on Windows than CouchDB.

Answer (score 1):

BerkeleyDB might be another option to check out, and it's lightweight enough. easy_install bsddb3 if you need a Python interface.

Answer (score 0):

[HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org) does this, but unfortunately it's Java rather than Python.

[Firebird SQL](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) might be closer to what you want, since it does seem to have a Python interface.

Comment: I don't think firebird comes with synchronization yet, can you point to a URL that shows otherwise?